# url {% url employes:check_matricule %} is not running in forms.py

Tags: python, django, url, data-uri

I want to execute the url"{% url employes:check_matricule %}"  to the data-url attribute in forms .py but the result  "404 page not found"

```
class EmployeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    matricule = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',
            'placeholder': 'Matricule1',
            'onkeyup': 'check_matricule(this);return false;',
            'data-url': '{% url employes:check_matricule %}',
        }
    ))
```

Comment: if possible share your, app urls, form html and view

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the `{% url %}` tag here - it isn't treated as a Django template.

You can also reverse URLs using [`reverse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) and [`reverse_lazy`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse-lazy). In your case, you need `reverse_lazy` because you don't want an error if the form is imported before the URLs have been loaded.

```
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

class EmployeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    matricule = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',
            'placeholder': 'Matricule1',
            'onkeyup': 'check_matricule(this);return false;',
            'data-url': reverse_lazy('employes:check_matricule'),
        }
    ))
```